# Don't know how to get access a script's variable from another script (different gameobject)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I'm currently working on a small speed dial. I have a script attached to the dial that waits for a speed measurement, then converts it into the proper angle and displays it. Now i want to get the speed measurement from the plane, and give it to the dial. But i cant figure it out. Here's the dial code:

```
static float minAngle = 70.64f;
    static float maxAngle = -269.69f;
    static RotateSpeedDial thisSpeedo;

    void Start () {
        thisSpeedo = this;
    }

    public static void ShowSpeed(float speed, float min, float max) {
        float ang = Mathf.Lerp(minAngle, maxAngle, Mathf.InverseLerp(min, max, speed));
        thisSpeedo.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0,0,ang);
    }
```

And here is the part of the plane code that gives the speed:

```
public Rigidbody rb;
public GameObject ScriptHolder = GameObject.Find("SpeedDial");
        public RotateSpeedDial = ScriptHolder.GetComponent<RotateSpeedDial>();

public void Update()
        {
            rb = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            RotateSpeedDial.ShowSpeed(rb.velocity.magnitude,0,100);
        }
```

Comment: Don't call `GetComponent` in `Update`, as it is an expensive operation. Call it only as many times as necessary (in this case, call it once in `Start`), and cache the results.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "I can't figure it out?" Are you asking why the code in the question does not compile? That would be because there's no variable name in this line: `public RotateSpeedDial = ScriptHolder.GetComponent<RotateSpeedDial>();`

Comment: @Ruzihm actually ^^ .. `GetComponent` was reworked a few versions ago and now they use a Hashsum so it is not as expensive as in the past .. however of course still you are right: One should store the reference and not do it every frame

Comment: @derHugo Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 0):

`RotateSpeedDial.ShowSpeed` is `static` so you don't need to get a reference to it via `GetComponent` at all.

Simply use it like

```
// Reference this via the Inspector and you don't need GetComponent at all
public Rigidbody rb;

// As a fallback get it ONCE on runtime
private void Awake()
{
    if(!rb) rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

public void Update()
{
    RotateSpeedDial.ShowSpeed(rb.velocity.magnitude, 0, 100);
}
```

---

However, you have a kind of *Singleton pattern* here which is quite **controversial** ... you should rather reference it via the Inspector.

Both `Find` and `GetComponent` can not be used in the field definition in the class. Also `ScriptHolder` can not be used to initialize a field in the class as it is assigned on runtime itself and not a static value. You need some method around it like e.g. `Awake` or `Start`.

Therefore you would have e.g.

```
// Reference all these via the Inspector using drag&drop
public Rigidbody rb;
// If you drag this in via the Inspector you wouldn't need the "ScriptHolder"
// at all.
public RotateSpeedDial rotateSpeedDial;
public GameObject ScriptHolder;

// Or as a fallback get them all on runtime ONCE like

// I use a little rule of thub: Get and initialize your own stuff at Awake
private void Awake()
{
    if(!rb) rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

// Get other objects stuff on Start 
// This way you can almost always be sure that the other stuff 
// is already initialized when you access it
private void Start()
{
    if(!rotateSpeedDial)
    {
        if(! ScriptHolder) ScriptHolder = GameObject.Find("SpeedDial");

        rotateSpeedDial = ScriptHolder.GetComponent<RotateSpeedDial>();
    }

    // Or simply use
    if(!rotateSpeedDial) rotateSpeedDial = FindObjectOfType<RotateSpeedDial>();
}

public void Update()
{
    rotateSpeedDial.ShowSpeed(rb.velocity.magnitude, 0, 100);
}
```

and then you wouldn't use any `static` at all in `RotateSpeedDial`:

```
float minAngle = 70.64f;
float maxAngle = -269.69f;

public void ShowSpeed(float speed, float min, float max) 
{
    var ang = Mathf.Lerp(minAngle, maxAngle, Mathf.InverseLerp(min, max, speed));
    transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.forward * ang;
}
```